# Solve errors "app:mergeDebugResources" and "File name must end with XML"

Tags: android-studio, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am trying to open [this project from GitHub](https://github.com/Anuj-Kumar-Sharma/Shuffler). Please help me solve the errors I am getting in this program, as I am very new to development. The errors are `app:mergeDebugResources caused by font (aparey italic)` and `File name must end with XML`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove .exe from all your drawable folders extension. It will then build successfully. Android accepts only .png, .jpg, .gif and .xml files as drawable resources.